# Overwrite MobileConnect List

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

I want to send an SMS to a specific subscribers that overwrite every 1 hrs. The SQL query segments a Synchronized DE subscriber based on some criteria and is stored (overwrite) in a data extension. SQL query run every 1 hrs and it will overwrite old subscribers data and import new subscriber data in to DE. I've created Import Definition in Contact Builder to import subscribers from the DE into a MobileConnect list. The issue with this is that it only add or update options are available in import, not overwrite.

Is there any way to overwrite MobileConnect list?

Answer (score 0):

No, at the moment you cannot overwrite the records of a list; anyway you could use a workaround importing all the content of this DE, then create a filtered list in mobile connect. You should schedule hourly the refresh of this mobile list in the automation studio, after that you could send an SMS.